# Android App. Mysql List View on a Tab Fragment

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-fragments, tabs

I assembled two Android Project into one. One is a "Tab Fragments" Project, the second is "Multiple JSON PHP MySQL Data inside Custom ListView".

I want to show the Data of my Mysql Db as List View on the first Fragment Tab.

here a Photo:
[My Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unFhr.jpg)

and here where I get the Error:
Tab1Fragment.java

```js
enter package de.transporte_express.transporteexpress21;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;

/**
 * Created by User on 2/28/2017.
 */

public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment{
    private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";

    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    ListView SubjectFullFormListView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String HttpURL = "http://example.com/script.php";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.activity_courier_menu);
        SubjectFullFormListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container);

        new ParseJSonDataClass(this).execute();
    }

        public class ParseJSonDataClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            public Context context;
            String FinalJSonResult;
            List<Subject> SubjectFullFormList;

            public ParseJSonDataClass(Context context) {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                this.context = context;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                HttpServiceClass httpServiceClass = new HttpServiceClass(HttpURL);

                try {
                    httpServiceClass.ExecutePostRequest();

                    if (httpServiceClass.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                        FinalJSonResult = httpServiceClass.getResponse();

                        if (FinalJSonResult != null) {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                            try {

                                jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonResult);
                                JSONObject jsonObject;
                                Subject subject;

                                SubjectFullFormList = new ArrayList<Subject>();

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                    subject = new Subject();

                                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    subject.Subject_Name = jsonObject.getString("shipping_date_c");

                                    subject.Subject_Full_Form = jsonObject.getString("shipping_time_c");

                                    subject.Billing_Address_City = jsonObject.getString("billing_address_city");

                                    subject.Billing_Address_Postalcode = jsonObject.getString("billing_address_postalcode");

                                    subject.Billing_Address_Country = jsonObject.getString("billing_address_country");

                                    subject.Arrival_Date = jsonObject.getString("arrival_date_c");

                                    subject.Arrival_Time = jsonObject.getString("arrival_time_c");

                                    subject.Shipping_Address_Postalcode = jsonObject.getString("shipping_address_city");

                                    subject.Shipping_Address_City = jsonObject.getString("shipping_address_postalcode");

                                    subject.Shipping_Address_Country = jsonObject.getString("shipping_address_country");

                                    subject.Description = jsonObject.getString("description");

                                    SubjectFullFormList.add(subject);
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(context, httpServiceClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

            {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                SubjectFullFormListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (SubjectFullFormList != null) {

                    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(SubjectFullFormList, context);

                    SubjectFullFormListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Here the CourierActivityMenu.java:

```js
package de.transporte_express.transporteexpress21;


import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class CourierActivityMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "CourierActivityMenu";

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_courier_menu);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting.");

        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "TAB1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "TAB2");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment(), "TAB3");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment(), "TAB4");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Errors:
Error:(45, 32) error: incompatible types: Tab1Fragment cannot be converted to Context
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Does someone has an Idea? Thanks

Comment: `Fragment` is not of type `Context `  I think you call a function that was not for fragment. You can minimize the your question in the line where the error occur.If you look at the inheritance hierarchy of Fragment you can see that it is directly a child of Object class.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be your SectionsPageAdapter.  In your CourierActivityMenu you set mSectionsPageAdapter to a new instance in onCreate but you also create a new SectionsPageAdapter in your setupViewPager. The activity won't know anything about the one you've created in the setup method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your Help. Could you please suggest me some Code to change? Nico

Comment: you need to use mSectionsPageAdapter that you set up in onCreate as your adapter in your setupViewPager method.  You didn't include any code for the adapter but you need to also make sure it extends FragmentPagerAdapter.